# Syntax error at or near "unnest"

Tags: postgresql

This request:

`unnest('{1,2}'::int[]);`

gives to me this error:

> syntax error at or near "unnest"

neither `unnest('{1,2}');` works

Why?

intire:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION result() RETURNS setof  users  AS
            $$
            DECLARE

            BEGIN
            unnest('{1,2}'::int[]);

RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM   users;
            END;
            $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
            SELECT result();
```

**EDIT**
The core  idea:

To retrive and manipualate with the bigint[] which is stored inside in a column.
So, i have got this:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = email_ LIMIT 1 INTO usr;`

Then, usr.chain contains some `bigint[]` data. For example, `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`. I want to save only the 4 last of them.

How to retrieve `{7,8,9,10}` and `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` and iterate over these arrays?

I only found the solution is to use `SELECT FROM unnest(usr.chain) AS x ORDER BY x ASC LIMIT (sdl - mdl) OFFSET mchain` and so on. but `unnest` function gives to me this stupid error. I'm really do not understand why it happends. It doesn't work in sucj easy case I wrote at the beginning of the question. `subarray` function doesn't work because of the data type is `bigint[]` not `int[]`

Futher more, the code `unnest(ARRAY[1,2])` gives to me the same error.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html
The same error for `array_append` function

Comment: Why? - because `unnest('{1,2}'::int[])` is not a valid (or complete) SQL statement

Comment: I'm a newbie in postgresql request. how to update this?

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: "fly on the roof" - man it's hard to grasp what you want. first of all, don't cast to anything unles its a text. what type is usr.chain? have you tried to read the manual? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy , i said usr.chain is bigint[] . `array_append` and `unnest` give me errors. How your link can help?

Comment: you cant call unnest , append or any function in in middle of nowhere . you must use "Select ...  into "  or  "for i IN array_lower(usr.chain, 1) .. array_upper(usr.chain, 1)   loop  begin ... end "  kinda structures or for Array_append you must assign result to a value  like "temp_value=array_append(usr.chain,11) " , link? you must learn basics :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to iterate over array:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION someresult(somearr bigint[] ) RETURNS setof     bigint  AS
$$
DECLARE
  i integer;
  x bigint;
BEGIN

for x in select unnest($1)
   loop
-- do something
   return next x;
   end loop;
 --  or 

FOR i IN array_lower($1, 1) .. array_upper($1, 1) 
    LOOP  
    -- do something like:
    return next ($1)[i];
    end loop;

 END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select someresult('{1,2,3,4}') ;
```

---

array_append ....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION someresult2(somearr bigint[],val bigint ) RETURNS  bigint[]  AS
$$
DECLARE
  somenew_arr bigint[];
BEGIN
somenew_arr = array_append($1, $2 );
return somenew_arr;
 END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
select someresult2('{1,2,3,4}' ,222) ;
```

so, here you have basic example how to iterate and append arrays. Now can you write step by step what you want to do, to achieve .